Laravel Bacon QR Code added into authenticator mobile app without site favicon
I just successfully installed antonioribeiro/google2fa-laravel and wrote all the necessary controllers and blades. It's working fine. But after scanning a QR Code, data in authenticator apps showing without my site favicon. Just showing site name and username ,etc.
How can I add an icon to data to be placed in mobile app?
I added favicon url to the bacon writer and getQRCodeInline() function $string but nothing changed.
